# Why does repl.it say "unindent does not match any other indent level"? I am trying to make a discord bot

Tags: python

```
if x == 10: 
    if message.content.startswith('$train'):
      await message.channel.send('You pack your opponent a menacing punch and he falls to the ground! come back later for round 2!')
      @commands.cooldown(1, 5000, commands.BucketType.user)
```

Comment: I moved your example into a code block, I hope I kept the spacing right. It seems like you are using inconsistent spacing. 4 for one block 2 for another. Keep it 4 spaces for each indentation and see if the problem is fixed.

Comment: Since this is a syntax error, it doesn't matter if its discord or not. You use await, meaning that this code fragment is in a larger function. But since you don't post the full traceback message we don't know if its even for this fragment or not. Better to post a small example that we can copy see the problem for ourselves. Once again, since this is a syntax error, it doesn't have to be sane running code. You could take the failing function, put it in a .py file and hack it down to the bare minimum example of the problem.

Comment: I did the above code but it did not work :((((

Comment: Right, but that code is bad for different reasons. You can't do await outside of a function for instance. The goal is to post code that has the fail of concern so that we can help.

Comment: That is fixed, but also when I do client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN')) It does not work and it says unexpected unindent. Im new to coding how do you solve this????

Comment: Please use a proper IDE such as PyCharm, VSCode etc instead of trying to write code using a text editor. Those tools will tell you exactly where your error is.

Comment: Since we don't see the `client.run` code, there isn't much we can do. A good code editor as suggested really helps, but in the end you need to focus on the few lines where that indentation error occurs and see where the indentation fails. You could post a dozen lines above the failing line, plus the failing line (and a few after) and we may be able to spot it.

Answer (score 0):

AS we do not have enough information about your project. So I can only fix the indentation of your code. The lines after the second `if` statements are indented to two spaces only rather than 4 spaces.

```
if x == 10: 
    if message.content.startswith('$train'):
        await message.channel.send('You pack your opponent a menacing punch and he falls to the ground! come back later for round 2!')
        @commands.cooldown(1, 5000, commands.BucketType.user)
```